# switch over enum / iota based type in golang

Tags: go

I defined an enumeration and struct type like so:

```
type NodeType int
const (
        City NodeType = iota
        Town
        Village
)

type AreaNode struct {
        Location Coord2D
        Type NodeType
}
```

and now I'm iterating over a series of nodes that each have a type

```
if node, ok := area.Nodes[coord]; ok {
    switch node.Type {
        case node.Type == City:
            // do something for City
        case node.Type == Town:
            // do something for Town
        case node.Type == Outpost:
            // do something for Outpost
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error: incompatible types in binary expression.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you either do a `switch` with no value, and put comparison expressions in each `case`, or you treat each case as a `==` for the checked value. e.g.:

```
if node, ok := area.Nodes[coord]; ok {
    switch node.Type {
        case  City:
            // do something for City
        case Town:
            // do something for Town
        case Outpost:
            // do something for Outpost
    }
}
```

The other `switch` syntax is used when you're switching between conditions that are not based on a single value. e.g.

```
switch {
    case node.Type == City:
        // do something for City
    case node.OtherParam == "foo":
        ///
}
```

Which means basically you're switching between binary conditions. Personally, I use it just to remove clutter from long if/else blocks that don't rely on a single value, but I rarely use it.

Comment: thanks... it won't let me accept for 5 more minutes :P but i will!